# Python web scrapping - Len(containers) returns 0 when I add class or id

Tags: python, jupyter, ironwebscraper

I am trying my first web scraping project in Jupyter notebook. When I try to find just **div** with the **find_all** function, It works well and returns the real length of containers.

```
all_page = doc.find_all('div')
len(all_page)
```

The answer is 262.
But, when I try to add class, length returns 0

```
all_page = doc.find_all('div', class_="full-width artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view")
len(all_page)
```

Now, The answer of length is 0

I am attaching a picture of a site I am trying to get data from.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIgRJ.jpg)

Can anyone please help me find the issue? I have read answers from here and tried to turn off JavaScript. But after doing that, I was unable to open the original website.

Comment: JFYI: There's a difference between "scrapping" and "scraping".

Comment: if the website is public, it's better if you provide a link to it. There are some pages that are dynamically generated by JavaScript, in this case it's necessary to use a library like selenium to automate user interaction to trigger that content creation.

Comment: @Matthias    corrected. Thanks .